# Move cells to next column if text in cell above contains ""

Tags: excel

I have Excel data that looks like this:

```
Date:
Name:
Reason:
Phonenumber:
```

The problem is, this is not always true as sometimes it can be:

```
Date:
Name:
Name:
Reason:
phonenumber
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to move the cells that are between `Date` and `phonenumber` to the next column. To do this I believe, since `Date` always is at the top, I could run a script that would "move, if "A6-1" contains Date".

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: How do you identify case 2 vs case 1 ?  Ie how do you know you have "name" and "name2" and not just "name" ?

Comment: The rows do this A3 Name: john smith then below that A4 Name: jane Smith

Comment: ah, they have the keyword "Name:" in there ?  ok

Comment: Try setting up a macro to do what you want .. then add some additional logic: ie: `if mid(cells(3,1).value, 1, 4) = "Name" then` .. and do your move .. try that first and see how it works.

Comment: sorry, that's the thing I was guessing with the "move" I don't know how to do it '(o_o)

Comment: Can you record a macro? try it .. see what code it generates ... it'll show you how to do it :)  then you just have to tweak it a bit to handle any special cases, etc.  once you have that base code, we can offer suggestions. Try something first ... we're here to help, not do your work for you ;)

Comment: I actually came up with a secondary way to do what I was trying, thank you for the advice, If you want put your answer into the answer your question and I'll make it my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming first `Date:` is in A1, in B1 and copied down to suit:

```
 =IF(OR(LEFT(A1)="N",LEFT(A1)="R"),A1,"")
```

Select ColumnB, Copy, Paste Special..., Values over the top. Filter ColumnsA:B and deselect `(Blanks)` for ColumnB. Select A2 down to the end, <kbd>Del</kbd>. Remove Filter.